# In Visual Studio project properties, how to make "All Configurations" selected by default instead of "Active"

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

When I am modifying project properties in Visual Studio, more often than not I need to change the selected Configuration to `All Configurations` before I make any changes. Is there any way for me to make `All Configurations` selected by default every time I enter the project properties window? It's a bit annoying to make a bunch of changes to the project settings only to realize you need to make those same changes to your other configurations because you forgot to select `All Configurations` in the beginning.

[image: See red circle]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property window would be always opened based on the Current Active `Solution Configuration`..

One manual workaround that I could think of is:
In the `.vcxproj`, the properties are set under the `PropertyGroup` xml tag. There would be one for `Release`.. You could copy paste the same...

***Example:***

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
    <TargetName>MyCustomTargetName</TargetName>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're suggesting here. Are you saying that one can manually edit the project file to set the desired properties, instead of using the Property Pages in the IDE? Yes, I suppose we could, but that isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: @CodyGray: The answer is the first part where it opens `Active Configuration`. The second part was to suggest copy paste the settings `manually`, instead of editing it in both Debug and Release configurations `UI` separately...

Comment: How is this more practical than selecting "All configuration" in circled combo box?

Comment: @sluki: It is just a work around for a case where in user had made the changes in one of the configuration assuming he had selected `All configuration`. It might be tedious to do a diff on each properties page, therefore my suggestion was to edit the `.vcxproj` file directly.